# Understand the meaning of Crontab timing

Tags: cron

I am trying to understand the crontab timing for the following :

```
00 */2 * * *
```

if I understood correctly , this runs every half hour , right ?

Comment: No, it runs every two hours.

Comment: This is useful: https://crontab.guru/

Comment: thanks @BenjaminW. the crontab.guru really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `crontab` manual

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with "" specifies skips of the number’s  value  through  the  range.
>          For  example,  "0-23/2"  can  be  used  in  the  hours  field  to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is
>          "0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22").  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say "every two hours", just use "*/2".

This runs every two hours.

```
 0 */2 * * *
```

Following runs every 30 minutes,

```
30 * * * *
```